# Column dimension in table for huge table

Tags: tables

I have been trying to figure out for days how to set the dimensions of this table.
It is too large for the page's dimension, i'd like to set the column's width or the table's width and the line's length could change automatically according to the text.
I have tried working with tabular* but it just didn't work out, maybe i used it wrong.

Thanks a lot !!

```
\usepackage[width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.8pt}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{placeins} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{textpos}



\begin{table}[H]            
        \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{c | c c}
        \hline
        \textbf{} & \textbf{Marnières}  & \textbf{Vignoble A} \\
        \hline \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Caractéristiques physiques} \\
        \hline \hline 
        Surface & ? ha & 4 ha \\
        \hline 
        Ecartement x & \multirow{2}{*}{240 x 100} & \multirow{2}{*}{160 x 75} \\
        distance intercep (cm x cm) & & \\
        \hline           
        Orientation & Nord-Est & Est \\
        \hline
        Altitude (m)& 215 & 100 \\
        \hline
        Drainage & Bon & Bon + pose de drains à 1,8m de profondeur, surtout dans la cuvette \\
        \hline
        Topographie & ? & Pente de 8\% \\ \hline
        Présence de carbonates & Oui & Oui \\
        \hline \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Caractéristiques de la vigne et du vin} \\
        \hline \hline
        Âge de la vigne & 8 ans & 4 ans\\ \hline
        Cépage & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Chardonnay} \\ \hline
        Clone & DUFT/D258 & Bourguignons peu productifs \\ \hline
        Prote-greffe & 450 pieds 5BB; 3000 pieds SO4 & principalement 3309C; quelques Gravesac
        Vin biologique & Non & Bio et biodynamie à partir de 2017 \\ \hline
        Début de production du vin & 2013 & 2017 \\ \hline
        Taux d'alcool potentiel & 11,9\% à 12,5\% & 10,3\% \\ \hline
        \hline \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Entretien de la vigne} \\
        \hline \hline
        Occupation avant la vigne & Pâture & Culture de maïs \\
        \hline 
        Avant la plantation & sous-solage à 60 cm entre les dents, labourage à 30 cm, 2 liersages perpendiculaires & 3 ans de repos puis labour \\
        \hline           
        Enherbement & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Permanent entre les rangs, pas sous le pied} \\
        \hline
        Taille & novembre à février, bois laissé dans la vigne & fin février à mars, bois exporté, méthode Guyot simple bourguignon \\
        \hline
        Effeuillage & léger, 2 mois avant les vendange & Partiellement côté nord, 2-3 semaines avant les vendanges \\
        \hline
        Passerillage & Non & Non \\ \hline
        Eclaircissage & Réduction à 2 grappes par pousse. Retrait du grapillon de la grappe qui fleurit 4 à 5 jours plus tard que la grape principale & Non \\ \hline
        Ebourgeonnage/épamprage & Ebourgeonnage manuel au niveau du pied puis au niveau du long bois pour ne laisser que les yeux les mieux placés (au-dessus) et éloignées de 15 à 20 cm & Les deux manuellement \\
        \hline \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \end{center}   
        \caption{Caractéristiques des parcelles et de la vigne des vignobles belges}
        \label{tab:caractparcellesbe}    
    \end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code example a MWE (minimize it, add the required lines to make it compilable, …).

Comment: See also here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options

Answer (score 1):

In the following example, I have used `tabularx` to make sure that the table fits onto the page. I have also removed the vertical lines and replaced some of the horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package (that you already load but don't use in your example).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedRight}X}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}          
\centering
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ZZZ}
        \toprule
         & Marnières  & Vignoble A \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Caractéristiques physiques} \\
        \midrule 
        Surface & ? ha & 4 ha \\

        Ecartement x distance intercep (cm x cm) & 240 x 100 & 160 x 75\\

        Orientation & Nord-Est & Est \\

        Altitude (m)& 215 & 100 \\

        Drainage & Bon & Bon + pose de drains à 1,8m de profondeur, surtout dans la cuvette \\

        Topographie & ? & Pente de 8\% \\ 
        Présence de carbonates & Oui & Oui \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Caractéristiques de la vigne et du vin} \\
        \midrule
        Âge de la vigne & 8 ans & 4 ans\\ 
        Cépage & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Chardonnay} \\
        Clone & DUFT/D258 & Bourguignons peu productifs \\ 
        Prote-greffe & 450 pieds 5BB; 3000 pieds SO4 & principalement 3309C; quelques Gravesac \\
        Vin biologique & Non & Bio et biodynamie à partir de 2017 \\ 
        Début de production du vin & 2013 & 2017 \\ 
        Taux d'alcool potentiel & 11,9\% à 12,5\% & 10,3\% \\ 
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Entretien de la vigne} \\
        \midrule
        Occupation avant la vigne & Pâture & Culture de maïs \\

        Avant la plantation & sous-solage à 60 cm entre les dents, labourage à 30 cm, 2 liersages perpendiculaires & 3 ans de repos puis labour \\

        Enherbement & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Permanent entre les rangs, pas sous le pied} \\

        Taille & novembre à février, bois laissé dans la vigne & fin février à mars, bois exporté, méthode Guyot simple bourguignon \\

        Effeuillage & léger, 2 mois avant les vendange & Partiellement côté nord, 2-3 semaines avant les vendanges \\

        Passerillage & Non & Non \\ 
        Eclaircissage & Réduction à 2 grappes par pousse. Retrait du grapillon de la grappe qui fleurit 4 à 5 jours plus tard que la grape principale & Non \\ 
        Ebourgeonnage/épamprage & Ebourgeonnage manuel au niveau du pied puis au niveau du long bois pour ne laisser que les yeux les mieux placés (au-dessus) et éloignées de 15 à 20 cm & Les deux manuellement \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}  
        \caption{Caractéristiques des parcelles et de la vigne des vignobles belges}
        \label{tab:caractparcellesbe}    
    \end{table}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `tabularx`. However, tables should have the caption above. You can use package `capt-of`, then you do not need the `float` package. By the way: Less lines in a tabular make it more readable.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{capt-of}


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\captionof{table}{Caractéristiques des parcelles et de la vigne des vignobles belges}
\label{tab:caractparcellesbe}    
\medskip\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} c | X X @{}}\hline
     & \textbf{Marnières}  & \textbf{Vignoble A} \\\hline \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Caractéristiques physiques} \\\hline \hline 
Surface & ? ha & 4 ha \\
            \hline 
Ecartement x & \multirow{2}{*}{240 x 100} & \multirow{2}{*}{160 x 75} \\
distance intercep (cm x cm) & & \\          \hline           
Orientation & Nord-Est & Est \\         \hline
Altitude (m)& 215 & 100 \\          \hline
Drainage & Bon & Bon + pose de drains à 1,8m de profondeur, surtout dans la cuvette\\\hline
Topographie & ? & Pente de 8\% \\ \hline
Présence de carbonates & Oui & Oui \\\hline \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Caractéristiques de la vigne et du vin} \\\hline \hline
Âge de la vigne & 8 ans & 4 ans\\ \hline
Cépage & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Chardonnay} \\ \hline
Clone & DUFT/D258 & Bourguignons peu productifs \\ \hline
Prote-greffe & 450 pieds 5BB; 3000 pieds SO4 & principalement 3309C; quelques Gravesac\\
Vin biologique & Non & Bio et biodynamie à partir de 2017 \\ \hline
Début de production du vin & 2013 & 2017 \\ \hline
Taux d'alcool potentiel & 11,9\% à 12,5\% & 10,3\% \\ \hline\hline \hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{Entretien de la vigne} \\\hline \hline
Occupation avant la vigne & Pâture & Culture de maïs \\\hline 
Avant la plantation & sous-solage à 60 cm entre les dents, labourage à 30 cm, 
    2 liersages perpendiculaires & 3 ans de repos puis labour \\\hline           
Enherbement & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Permanent entre les rangs, pas sous le pied}\\ \hline
Taille & novembre à février, bois laissé dans la vigne & fin février à mars, 
    bois exporté, méthode Guyot simple bourguignon \\\hline
Effeuillage & léger, 2 mois avant les vendange & Partiellement côté nord, 2-3 
        semaines avant les vendanges \\\hline
Passerillage & Non & Non \\ \hline
Eclaircissage & Réduction à 2 grappes par pousse. Retrait du grapillon de la 
    grappe qui fleurit 4 à 5 jours plus tard que la grape principale & Non \\ \hline
Ebourgeonnage/épamprage & Ebourgeonnage manuel au niveau du pied puis au 
    niveau du long bois pour ne laisser que les yeux les mieux placés (au-dessus) 
    et éloignées de 15 à 20 cm & Les deux manuellement \\\hline \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```